# A blue message, which vanishes

Tags: support, user-interface

When I vote (or comment?) I get recently a blue message which vanishes before I catch it. Do you have any idea about this colorful (well, just blue) info item?

Comment: Use a video screen capture software, then extract a single frame from the video! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recall receiving three kinds of blue messages when voting:

- Messages indicating the number of votes remaining for that day (or in that proposal at Area 51).
- Messages about voting only answers (but no similar thing exists for questions, see quid's comment). Once or twice I have given a series of votes to answers without voting their questions, and the system has reminded me that I should vote answers, too.
- Sometimes downvoting triggers a message suggesting to leave a comment to explain the vote.

If you have a lengthy discussion in the comments, you also get a notice, but I don't remember if it is blue as well.

I wonder if a list of these blue messages is found in some documentation or a meta.SE thread.

Comment: Nice summary. On the second point: no I think it only exists in one way, see [the blog post on it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) according to which it is triggered after 15 votes on answers. The point is *globally* there is a (perceived) lack of votes on questions, thus this mechanism to get more votes on questions. This is also present in the "electorate badge" where there is a lower bound on the number of votes on Q (not A).